# how to Enable soft delete for blobs or containers in azure storage accounts using rest api or python library

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blob, soft-delete

I am searching all over the internet and read already many MS docs but nothing regarding enabling soft delete for an azure blob storage using API.
I want to Enable soft delete for blobs and setup a retention policy like in the picture

[image: Storage Account -> Data protection Blade]

Comment: Hi @Eli m have you tried in powershell or azure cli commands?

Comment: Hi @Venkatesan, no, i am writing a python script for it and therefore would like to do this via REST API or a python library

Answer (score 1):

I could able to get this done using REST API `PUT` method by Setting `DeleteRetentionPolicy` property of Blob Storage. I have referred from this [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/blob-services/set-service-properties?tabs=HTTP#deleteretentionpolicy).

*API*

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/resourceGroups/<RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<ACCOUNT_NAME>/blobServices/default?api-version=2022-09-01
```

*BODY*

```
{ 
"properties": { 
    "deleteRetentionPolicy": { 
    "enabled": true, 
    "days": <DAYS>, 
    "allowPermanentDelete": true 
    }, 
    "isVersioningEnabled": true } 
}
```

***RESULTS:***

[image]

***IN STORAGE ACCOUNT***

[image]